# How do I resolve the error described in the description below?

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy, mule

Groovy code -

```
def initialList = payload
def finalList = []
def ost = flowVars.current_objectstore_time
for(int i = 0;i<10000;i++){
    def pattern = "yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"
    def currentFile = initialList[i]
    def fileDateString = currentFile[0..14]
    def date = Date.parse(pattern, fileDateString)
    if(date>=ost){
        finalList.add(currentFile)
    } else{
        break
    }
}

finalList
```

---

The payload is a java ArrayList consisting of a few hundred files derived from an SMB directory read component in a Mule 3 flow. Sample name of file - `[20201127-124819249_KATMP_9090000341616_20201127023750364.txt]`

Everything works fine but strangely, when the arrayList consists of less than 169 elements groovy is throwing -

```
Exception stack is:
Failed to invoke ScriptComponent{flow3.component.720934259}. Component that caused exception is: ScriptComponent{flow3.component.720934259}. (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:58)
  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
  Script252.run(Script252.groovy:8)
  org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321)
  org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72)
  javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
  org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable.runScript(Scriptable.java:372)
  org.mule.module.scripting.component.ScriptComponent.doInvoke(ScriptComponent.java:78)
  org.mule.component.AbstractComponent.invokeInternal(AbstractComponent.java:120)
  (73 more...)
.
```

When the number of elements in the ArrayList are greater than 170 then it works just fine. How do i fix this, thanks...

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace and relate the line numbers to your code.

Comment: Hi i have added the full stack trace, could you take a look now, thanks,,

Comment: Is this all? Is there not "cause" inside that one giving the real error? Other than that my guess is your "optimistic" 10k loop - have you tried using a for-loop directly over initialList?

Comment: Hi @Hariprasathudayakumar, please confirm that there are no missing lines of the stack trace. because it is not pointing to any cause as cfrick mentioned. Also please add any error messages too.